# Monotouch socket problem

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

`BeginSend` function does not throw exception when I disconnect iPad from Network. Interesting thing is that `OnSend` callback function calls and result. 
`Iscompleted` returns true.

If I call another overloaded function with error code, it always return `success`

```
tcpAsyCl.BeginSend(
             write_data, 
             0, 
             write_data.Length, 
             SocketFlags.None, 
             out error, 
             new AsyncCallback(OnSend), 
             null);

if (error != SocketError.Success)
      throw new Exception("Not connected"); //never goes her
```

Does anyone know this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as It's an **async** call! You can't verify the result in the line below... I'm sure you have a method that you can hook up to get the correct error.

**Asynchronous calls** are created in a new thread and it's there that you need to wait for the answer. Not in your main thread, or that would be a **Synchronous** call.

here is a [**list of all methods**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) that you can use

I would strongly suggest that you take a deep look at this document

> [Using an Asynchronous Client Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx)

Comment: When I use this form it never throw exception. tcpAsyCl.BeginSend(write_data, 0, write_data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null); But under Windows it throw exception when netwrok unavailable.In iOS I can't fix the disconnected status.

Comment: all your errors will be in the `OnSend` callback as that's where you tell the Async method to return info to, you can use a delegate instead a method. See link on updated answer.

Comment: Add the linked document with all the code and explanation that you need for using `System.Net.Sockets` in an async call

Comment: I try this metods but didn't help me.When I disconnect device from network it continues send data an in OnSend client.EndSend(result) return 14 byte during disconneced time.